# Prevent a date from happening in the past

Tags: 7, entities, datetime

I have a CCK field that is a date. I want to prevent people entering a date that has happend in the past. I know you can set **Years back and forward** and I have set this to *-0:+2* but this just limits the calendar. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Drupal's Form API allows you to add your own validation functions to a form. There is an example for a date field validation function in [this forum topic](http://drupal.org/node/1146654#comment-4430498). Documentation is [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#validate).

Answer (score 2):

I have been involved on a patch that would add this feature to the JavaScript popup, you can see more on [issue queue](http://drupal.org/node/625264). Right now there is a working patch, but it's not quite there yet IMO.

You shouldn't rely on the JavaScript alone as that can be circumvented and should add a custom validation like marcvangend describes. This can be done by adding a validation handler and checking the value for the data and comparing it with the current data.

Answer (score 0):

I think, What you are looking for is

1) `hook_date_combo_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context)`

This hook let you alter the calender's element for "date combo" field type.

2) `hook_date_popup_process_alter(&$element, &$form_state, $context)`

This hook let you alter the calender's element for "date popup" field type.

In both the cases, to prevent a user from enter past dates, all you need to do is - 
define "minDate = 0" inside #datepicker_options array.